# Hybrid Mobile App Development With Ionic Frame work, Node.Js and MySql

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

**Hi Users**,
  I am new to this forum and mobile app development. i am web application developer using php and its framework now planning to develop mobile app for my web applications, i preferred ionic framework, NodeJs and MySql.

**My Questions**

1. Is ionic,node.js and MySql is a correct combination? will this combination deliver efficient product.If not what will be the right combination ?exception for mysql many one will prefer mongodb for nodejs but in my organization its not preferable.
2. I need a simple login app using Ionic and NodeJs.

Comment: You can develop ionic app with the combination of angular js and mysql.  It will helps to develop a nice apps.

Comment: Thank You Currently working on it.